# Parsing ISO datetime+microseconds format with Python

Tags: python

In one of my "tool" I need list of docker images sorted by date. Docker API libs works fine, returns information about images but all dates are in strange format like: `2020-01-14T17:58:54.048970797Z`, question is how parse last 3 digits before 'Z'?

```
a = '2020-01-14T17:58:54.048970797Z'
print(datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"))
```

returns error:

`ValueError: time data '2020-01-14T17:58:54.048970797Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`

Without "Z" on both (date and format string) sides returns:
`ValueError: unconverted data remains: 797`

A quick workaround is to truncate the last 4 characters before parsing, but I'm wondering how it should be properly parsed?

Comment: This "strange format" is ISO 8601

Comment: I know what ISO 8601 is, but still don't know how to parse in python extra digits before "Z"...