# parsing datetime beyond microseconds in Python in unknown ISO format

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

I'm trying to parse this datetime:

```
t = '2021-08-21 11:23:45.180999936'
```

using `datetime` strptime function:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').time()
```

I'm struggling with the last element of the datime, which I assume to be microseconds (`%f`), but get this error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 936 strptime
```

So if I understood the value error says the datetime is three digits too long for the last part to be a microsecond. What is the right way of parsing this datetime if not with microseconds? What is the ISO format of this datetime?

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716553/parsing-iso-datetimemicroseconds-format-with-python) (unanswered) question with a different (related?) format (with `Z`-suffix).

Comment: The time is in nanoseconds which isn’t supported by `datetime`. If you don’t need the accuracy, truncate with `t[:-3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, strftime and strptime allow only up to 6 decimal places. They aren't fully ISO 8601.

> `%f` Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded to 6 digits.

Taken from [`datetime.datetime.fromisodatetime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

> **Caution** This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of datetime.isoformat(). A more full-featured ISO 8601 parser, `dateutil.parser.isoparse` is available in the third-party package [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to parse the string to datetime or Timestamp objects

```
import pandas as pd
t = '2021-08-21 11:23:45.180999936'
t1 = pd.Timestamp(t)
t2 = pd.to_datetime(t)
```

The output is `Timestamp` object

```
Timestamp('2021-08-21 11:23:45.180999936')
```

Another way is using the library

```
from datetime import datetime
t = '2021-08-21 11:23:45.180999936'
t3 = datetime.fromisoformat(t.split('.')[0])
t4 = datetime.strptime(t.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The output is `datetime` object

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 21, 11, 23, 45)
```

Comment: You definitely don’t need to use pandas to parse a ISO 8601 datetime. Underneath pandas uses dateutil, which is recommended in the official datetime docs.

Comment: but I read that ISO 8601 format has 3 decimal places, so `t` is not in that format, no?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the ISO does not set a limit on decimal places.

Comment: oh wikipedia says there is no limit in decimal places, but for Microsoft SQL Server it's 3 dec pl

Comment: the [ISO 8601](https://web.archive.org/web/20171019211402/https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-1.pdf) says on page 23: "The interchange parties, dependent upon the application, shall agree the number of digits in the decimal fraction."